# Prevent data tampering in Response

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tampering

While reading *The Web Application Hacker's Handbook*, I tried to make a small test on my own website (ASP.NET MVC3).

I have a model which it contains two fields, the first field is a **disabled** dropdownlist.
The second is an **enabled** text field.
The first field is disabled from the View.chtml and added 
`new {disabled="disabled"}` as a paratemer.

Here is what happened to me, I ran *Burp Suite* tool as a proxy and trapped the response.
In the response, I removed the `disabled="disabled"`attribute from HTML, then forwarded the response to the browser. Oviuosly, the page now has two enabled fields.

The question is how to prevent tampering fields using tools such as *Burp Suite*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. For that matter you can't be sure that a post back you receive in your controller is the result from your view in a browser. Just posting whatever you want using some script is easy and something hackers frequently do.

The bottom line is. Never trust input and always validate it is permissible.

Comment: Ok,for this particular issue, what about comparing the model on GET and POST in controller? I mean comparing readonly attrbute(s)?

Comment: Why do you need to read read only data other than the primary key? After all you send it to the client in the first place. And a general thing that will help against hackers is a [AntiForgeryToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492767.aspx)

Comment: An easy way of ignoring read only data is using a Bind attribute and excluding fields.